# Can I replace my lawn mower's blade with any brand blade?

Tags: lawn, lawn-repair, lawn-mower

I have a Murray lawn mower (Model 20223X12A). The Tecumseh engine model number is TVS 90 4354K. I measured the blade diagonally and it is about 19.5 inches long. It is just a regular blade.

I wanted to know if I can install any type blade or brand as long as the length is the same. I was thinking of getting a 3 in 1 blade.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In principle, sure - as long as it will fit. Most blades are made to similar strength standards.

Check very carefully that the hole spacings are correct - and that you can tighten the bolt/bolts fully, as you really don't want a blade flying off at speed.

Comment: Which hole spacing are you referring to? My mower has a bolt with a big washer that attaches to the shaft which holds the blade.

Comment: The ones that have a central bolt usually have locating rods or other devices. If it is a single bolt with no other fixings, then you have it easy :-)